# Bug on url() in scss files on rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm having troubles with the `url()` css function in my rails 7 project. I reproduced it on a brand new one: https://github.com/paul-mesnilgrente/rails-7-url, see this commit: https://github.com/paul-mesnilgrente/rails-7-url/commit/77e1379cd98827f43b02605852220cd3db93ce06

It uses sass (see package.json) with cssbundling-rails and sprockets-rails. If you look at the `app/assets/stylesheets/application.sass.scss`, I have: `background-image: url('images/background.jpg')`. And the `background.jpg` file is `app/assets/images/background.jpg`.

I tried several paths to include that background (`../images/background.jpg`, `/images/background.jpg` etc.) but nothing works. The compiled result in the development environment should have a digest hash appended to it but there's nothing and the path is only translated to `/images/background.jpg` which gives a 404. This makes me thing that sprockets doesn't find the background image so it doesn't "compile" that path.

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem which was actually pretty dumb. In manifest.js we have this line by default `//= link_tree ../images`.

And the thing is, rails doesn't look for the assets relatively to your stylesheet or even relatively to `app/assets`. It's only relative to those `//= link_tree ...` paths.

So the right path, which I hadn't tried before was `url("background.jpg")`.

**Side note :** If you use libraries like datatables which are including relative paths, you need to add something link this in manifest.js `//= link_tree ../../../node_modules/datatables.net-zf/css`

Comment: You have to also add it in assets.rb. For example I would add:
`Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("node_modules/leaflet-draw/dist")` and in manifest.js, I would add:
`//= link_tree "../../../node_modules/leaflet-draw/dist"`